# Data binding throwing exception in async thread

Tags: c#, uwp, xamarin.forms

I'm currently writing a simple Xamarin.Forms chat application for learning.

This application has a ListView which has been binded to an ObservableCollection. By right, whenever I add an object to the ObservableCollection, it should show up in the list.

I have an asynchronous thread which polls the server every second for messages and then adds that message to the ObservableCollection, which then appears in the ListView.

This works fine on Android, but doesn't seem to work on UWP for some strange reason.

The exception that I get in the console is a  `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException`.

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
    ObservableCollection<MessageListItem> messageList = new ObservableCollection<MessageListItem>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Bind the ListView to the ObservableCollection
        MessageListView.ItemsSource = messageList;

        //Start listening to messages
        var messagesTask = connection.GetMessagesAsync(messageList);
    }
```

GetMessagesAsync():

```
    public async Task GetMessagesAsync(ObservableCollection<MessageListItem> collection)
    {
        string watermark = null;

        while(true)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Reading message every 1 second");

            var activitySet = await Client.Conversations.GetActivitiesAsync(MainConversation.ConversationId, watermark);
            watermark = activitySet?.Watermark;

            foreach(Activity activity in activitySet.Activities)
            {
                if (activity.From.Name == "MarsBot")
                {
                    //Add object to binded collection
                    collection.Add(new MessageListItem(activity.Text, activity.From.Name));
                }             
            }

            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I'm surprised this even gets going, is there no Task.Run anywhere?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Sorry but, is that needed? I was under the assumption that I could just call the async method and it would work asynchronously according to this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx

Comment: It only works when you await it, and you can't do that from a constructor. I would expect this to block, is this the exact code that runs on Android? Any code using messageTask?

Comment: Yes this is the exact code. Nothing uses messageTask. My main objective is to just have a background thread polling the server with HTTP every one second. Do you know how I can achieve this?

Comment: You should start this as a (non-async) method with Task.Run() and then look for a thread-safe version of the ObservableCollecion.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your code. It would still be better to keep a reference to the task you are started to prevent it from being garbage collected but more important to be able to cancel it when leaving. The call to Client.Conversations.GetActivitiesAsync() is delegated to another thread and your collection is updated in the main thread so that should not be the issue. The COMException can have several reasons. It could be something wrong with your XAML. Can you get the call stack and the error code of the exception (activating native debugging and loading system symbols will help) ?